# Uncaught TypeError: d3.csv(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
    var allData;
    d3.csv('hello.csv', function(d) {
      return {
        id: +d.id,
        state: d.state
      };
    }).then(function(data) {
      allData = data;
    });
```

Above code is causing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: d3.csv(...).then is not a function

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using? v4 or earlier?

Comment: @AndrewReid   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: The Fetch-API using promises was introduced by D3 **v5** whereas you are using **v3**, hence, the error. Check the API [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md) for v3 to see how it's done in that version.