# parsing csv with d3.csv

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing

I am trying to pare a csv file and I have tried several methods in js without luck. I am quite new at coding and got stuck here.

Here is my first try. I get error messages saying "Uncaught TypeError: d3.csv(...).then is not a function"

```
d3.csv("/data/testfile.csv").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

I tried this code as well. the alert of bfile shows me correct values but I still need to parse it....

```
var file = document.getElementById("file input").files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {  
  bfile = e.target.result 
  alert(bfile);   // this shows bfile

  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

The third attempt. Here it complains and says that "then is not a function".

```
d3.csv("/data/cities.csv").then(function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.population = +d.population;
    d["land area"] = +d["land area"];
  });
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

This is what I would like to achieve after the csv pasing:

```
=> {city: "seattle", state: "WA", population: 652405, land area: 83.9}
```

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using? Only in v5 does `d3.csv` return a Promise, which is needed for `then`. IIRC, in prior versions, `d3.csv` took a callback as a second argument.

Comment: I am using d3... But I think I have tried that as well. I started with something like this but:

d3.csv("testdata.csv", function (data) {
           
          });

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

The version of D3 you are using, seems to not to support JavaScript's [*Promises*](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).
See similar question: [Uncaught TypeError: d3.csv(...).then is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625450/uncaught-typeerror-d3-csv-then-is-not-a-function)

This is how you call function in D3 **prior to version 5**:

```js
d3.csv("file.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
});
```

It uses *asynchronous callbacks* to load data (like the `function(error, data)` argument above).
See also the [example from the D3 v3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md#csv).

Since D3 **version 5** instead of *asynchronous callbacks* the modern *Promises* got introduced, so the call became:

```js
d3.csv("file.csv").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

See the release page on [breaking changes in v5](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/main/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50):

Like [commented by BallpointPen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890840/parsing-csv-with-d3-csv#comment111235163_62890840):

> Only in v5 does d3.csv return a Promise, which is needed for then
> `then()` function

### Solution

From expected output:

```js
{city: "seattle", state: "WA", population: 652405, land area: 83.9}
```

we can suppose your CSV looks like:

```
city, state, population, land area
"seattle", "WA", 652405, 83.9
```

We need the CSV input example to reproduce.

#### D3

With older versions of D3 (like v3):

```
d3.csv("/data/testfile.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
});
```

With newer versions of D3 (like v5):

```
d3.csv("/data/testfile.csv").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data[0]);
});
```

#### Alternative CSV-parser

Why not use [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/#header) which claims to be:

> The powerful, in-browser CSV parser for big boys and girls

Example usage:

```js
var csv = 'city, state, population, land area\n"seattle", "WA", 652405, 83.9';

var results = Papa.parse(csv, {
    header: true  // Key data by field name instead of index/position
});
```

Output (copied from console):

```
{
  data: [
    {city: "seattle", state: "WA", population: " 652405", "land area": " 83.9"}
  ],
  errors: [],
  meta: {aborted: false, cursor: 64, delimiter: ",", fields: ["city", " state", " population", " land area"], linebreak: "↵", truncated: false}
}
```

or parse without header-row as simple array:

```
{
  data: [
    ["city", " state", " population", " land area"],
    ["seattle", " "WA"", " 652405", " 83.9"]
  ],
  errors: [],
  meta: {delimiter: ",", linebreak: "↵", aborted: false, truncated: false, cursor: 64}
}
```

It has a [demo-page](https://www.papaparse.com/demo) to try CSV-parsing online.